# how to use Linq or extension methods to satisy this condition on CanExecute?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an `ObservableCollection<Data> Items`

Data has a "Columns" property on it which is again an `ObservableCollection<Column>`.

A Column object has a boolean property called "IsActive".

I have a case where I need to determine if all "Items" have the "Columns" property and if so, 
all the columns should either have "IsActive" as true or false but not both.

The trick is i need to put this logic in CanExecute of a button.. I will need to make this as  efficient and fast as possible...Any ideas?
The struture is:

```
public class MyClass
{
     public ObservableCollection<Data> Items
    {
         get{return _items;}
     }
}

public class Data
{
    public ObservableCollection<Column> Columns
    {
         get{return _columns;}
     }
}

public class Column
{

   public bool IsActive{ get; set;}

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Show some structure of `Data` and `Column`

Comment: "I heard that canexecute fires continuously" who said that and where?

Comment: I added structure which is sample of what i have

Comment: Can we also see the XAML where you declare your Bindings?

Comment: what do you mean by 'if all "Items" have the "Columns" property'?

Comment: they could be null in which case i need to return false.

Comment: @H.B. the basic implementation does. I know that prism's DelegateCommand doesn't though.

Comment: @Baboon: What "basic implementation"?

Comment: @H.B. when you create a class that implements ICommand, [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.routedcommand.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This smells like premature optimization. Have you measured the speed of a simplistic approach? Iterating through a few not too big collections will only take a few milliseconds on a modern CPU.

If you want to use LINQ to compute if all `Column` objects are either active or inactive you can use this expression.

```
public Boolean CanExecute {
  get {
    var aggregate = Items
      .SelectMany(i => i.Columns)
      .Aggregate(
        new {
          IsEmpty = true,
          AllAreActive = true,
          AllAreInactive = true
        },
        (a, c) => new {
          IsEmpty = false,
          AllAreActive = a.AllAreActive && c.IsActive,
          AllAreInactive = a.AllAreInactive && !c.IsActive
        }
    );
    return !aggregate.IsEmpty && (aggregate.AllAreActive || aggregate.AllAreInactive);
  }
```

This code will iterate over all elements in all collections. You can improve on this by using a `for` loop and breaking it when both boolean variables becomes false. This can also by done in LINQ using `TakeWhile` using a predicate with side effects but a simple `for` loop is probably easier to understand.

If you decide that a simplistic approach is too slow you need to keep track of the `CanExecute` property at the `MyClass` level. You can do this by setting up change notification handlers for all the `ObservableCollection` instances. It is somewhat tedious because you have two levels of collections but it will ensure that whenever a `Column` is added or removed from a collection or the `IsActive` property is changed the boolean variable backing `CanExecute` in `MyClass` is updated.

Initially `Column` has to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
class Column : INotifyPropertyChanged {

  Boolean isActive;

  public Boolean IsActive {
    get { return this.isActive; }
    set {
      if (this.isActive == value)
        return;
      this.isActive = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("IsActive");
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  protected void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName) {
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
      handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }

}
```

`Data` has to expose the desired property which for lack of better name I have called `AllColumnsAreActiveOrInactive` and changes to this property is signaled by implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

To track the status of all columns the `CollectionChanged` of the `Column` collection is handled. When a new `Column` is added the value of `AllColumnsAreActiveOrInactive` can be recomputed without iterating the `Column` collection. However, when `IsActive` changes on a single `Column` or when a `Column` is removed the collection has to be iterated to determine the new value of the `AllColumnsAreActiveOrInactive`.

```
class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged {

  readonly ObservableCollection<Column> columns;

  Boolean allColumnsAreActive = true;

  Boolean allColumnsAreInactive = true;

  Boolean allColumnsAreActiveOrInactive = false;

  public Data() {
    this.columns = new ObservableCollection<Column>();
    this.columns.CollectionChanged += CollectionChanged;
  }

  public ObservableCollection<Column> Columns { get { return this.columns; } }

  public Boolean AllColumnsAreActiveOrInactive {
    get { return this.allColumnsAreActiveOrInactive; }
    set {
      if (value == this.allColumnsAreActiveOrInactive)
        return;
      this.allColumnsAreActiveOrInactive = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("AllColumnsAreActiveOrInactive");
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  protected void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName) {
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
      handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }

  void CollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset) {
      RecomputeAllColumnsAreActiveOrInactive();
      return;
    }
    if (e.OldItems != null) {
      foreach (var item in e.OldItems.Cast<Column>())
        item.PropertyChanged -= ColumnPropertyChanged;
      RecomputeAllColumnsAreActiveOrInactive();
      return;
    }
    if (e.NewItems != null) {
      foreach (var column in e.NewItems.Cast<Column>()) {
        column.PropertyChanged += ColumnPropertyChanged;
        this.allColumnsAreActive = this.allColumnsAreActive && column.IsActive;
        this.allColumnsAreInactive = this.allColumnsAreInactive && !column.IsActive;
      }
      UpdateAllColumnsAreActiveOrInactive();
    }
  }

  void ColumnPropertyChanged(Object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    if (e.PropertyName == "IsActive") {
      var column = sender as Column;
      RecomputeAllColumnsAreActiveOrInactive();
    }
  }

  void RecomputeAllColumnsAreActiveOrInactive() {
    this.allColumnsAreActive = this.columns.All(c => c.IsActive);
    this.allColumnsAreInactive = this.columns.All(c => !c.IsActive);
    UpdateAllColumnsAreActiveOrInactive();
  }

  void UpdateAllColumnsAreActiveOrInactive() {
    AllColumnsAreActiveOrInactive = this.columns.Any()
      && (this.allColumnsAreActive || this.allColumnsAreInactive);
  }

}

class Column : INotifyPropertyChanged {

  Boolean isActive;

  public Boolean IsActive {
    get { return this.isActive; }
    set {
      if (this.isActive == value)
        return;
      this.isActive = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("IsActive");
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  protected void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName) {
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
      handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }

}
```

To complete this solution the `Column/Data` collection approach has to be repeated for the `Data/MyClass` collection.

Comment: Brilliant, works as expected. Thanks for the really good answer. I would thumbs up twice if I could.